# Call to Mixlib::ShellOut detected. Executing commands on your machine is not safe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have several command in my Chef cookbook that make use of `Mixlib::ShellOut` e.g.

```
cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(format('getent group %s', 'test'))
cmd.run_command

cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(format('getent pasword %s', 'test'))
cmd.run_command
```

Unfortunately, my build process keeps failing with the following error, largely due to some config I cannot change:

> Call to Mixlib::ShellOut detected. Executing commands on your machine is not safe!

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think this error is thrown by your build system, and not Chef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use back ticks.

```
`ls -ltr >> logs.txt 2>&1`
```